# Sass is concatenating instead of adding?

Tags: css, math, sass

I need to define a width in my SCSS code as so:

```
#example {
  width: $currentWidth + 349 !important;
}
```

Where `$currentWidth` is defined by the loop.

However, Sass always ends up concatenating the two numbers instead of doing the arithmetic.

I have also tried:

`width: #{$currentWidth + 349}px !important;`

Which still results in concatenation.

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong? I know this is incredibly basic, but I also can't seem to find good information on how Sass handles arithmetic

Comment: Is `$currentWidth` a string or a number?  If it is a string, then it will concatenate.  Sass can only do arithmetic if both entities are of the number type (ie. Sass interprets `"10" + 349` the same way it does `"meatloaf" + 349`).

Comment: The most straight forward solution for this particular case could be: `width: $currentWidth + 349px !important` which works like a charm and is very straight forward.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Assuming `$currentWidth` is an integer.

**SASS:**

```
$currentWidth: 30;

#example {
  width: unquote( ($currentWidth + 349) + 'px ' + !important );
}
```

**CSS OUTPUT:**

```
#example {
  width: 379px !important;
}
```

You can test it here:

http://sass-lang.com/try.html

Comment: By concatenating the unit onto the integer like this, you're getting a string.  This is wrong and you should *never* do this *ever*.

Comment: Exactly what I said:  `($currentWidth + 349) + 'px '` is a string.  You should **never** do this if you're trying to change a unitless value to a united value.

Comment: Okay I sort of see what you are saying, but you didn't really explain why to "never" do this. Also, what would you recommend? Would this `#example {
  width: abs($currentWidth + 349) + px !important;
}` be a better way?

Comment: No.  You're not getting it.  It's still a string.

Comment: And you still haven't explained why this is an issue.

Comment: This syntax is very uncomfortable. I thought it was a best practice to assign integer value to variable instead of pixel value. Isn't it? (`$my-width: 100;` instead of `$my-width: 100px;`)

Comment: The most straight forward solution for this particular case could be: `width: $currentWidth + 349px !important` which works like a charm and is very straight forward.