# scss how can i add +1px in media Query

Tags: sass

i try to use scss variable in mediaQuery and
i want to add 1px  in $min
the code is like this

i marked � in my code that point occur error

```css
$mobile: "400px" !default; // sm
$phablet: "550px" !default; //  md
$tablet: "750px" !default; //  wmd
$desktop: "1000px" !default; // lg
$desktophd: "1200px" !default; //  wlg 
$full: "9999px" !default; 
$null: "0px" !default; 


@mixin response($max:9999px,$min:0px) {
    @media only screen and (max-width: $max) and (min-width: $min + 1px) {//�
      @content; 
  }
}

@include response ($full,$mobile) {
    .myPage__myProducts > .col:nth-child(3n + 1){
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

it trans to css "400px1px"  i want 401px
how can i amke it possible?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sass is concatenating instead of adding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639175/sass-is-concatenating-instead-of-adding)

Comment: Why did you use quotation mark in your variables declaration ? If you remove them, it will work just fine.

Comment: @Amaury Hanser thanks!!!!!!!

Comment: @MINJAKIM Glad I could help ;)